# Line in crossplot not visible when using log scale

Tags: ocean, techlog

I faced an issue when I try to draw lines in a crossplot.
When I use logarithmic scale types for a crossplot, the lines created in the crossplot are not visible.

This can be reproduced with setupcrossplot.cpp (at around line 150).
If I replace

```
  crossplot.setYScaleType(WidgetScaleTypeLinear);

  crossplot.setXScaleType(WidgetScaleTypeLinear);
```

with

```
  crossplot.setYScaleType(WidgetScaleTypeTypeLogarithmic);

  crossplot.setXScaleType(WidgetScaleTypeTypeLogarithmic);
```

The lines which are drawn at the chart parameters becomes not visible.

Is there anything missing to visualize the lines, or is this a bug ?

The version I’m using is 2013.1.0 (r118949).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, make sure that none of the points in the polyline has negative coordinates, because we won't display that polyline in logarithmic scales.